# spinner on change reload screen with new value

Tags: java, android, xml

I am realy new to android, but I am impressed with spinners. I just want to know if it is possible to have a spinner (populated with cities) and when user selects a city, then refresh and show records relevant to that city?

I will handle the json parsing and all, but I want to know if it is possible? or is there a better way for city filtering? any examples would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Once you changed the data of your first spinner, store your second spinner adapter with new data and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of your second spinner adapter.

For example I assume you stores the data in `list`. Before stores the new data clear your previous data using `list.clear()` and then store the new data. Then call

`spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

I hope this will help you.